# Need to stop a div from getting scroll in JQM

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

This is my http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/Lhb5Y/ implementation

Basically i have content like this

```
<div data-role="content">
   <div><!--Contains a button --></div>
   <div><ul>..<!--Contains a list -->...</ul></div>
</div>
```

Now i want to make the div which contains the button fixed and should not scroll while the list should scroll. How to do this in JQM?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You want to position the `div` with the button as `fixed` so that it always appears at the top. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/mz6rn/). Below is a summary of the details.

```
<div data-role="content">
   <div style="position: fixed; top:0px; height: 100px;"><!--Contains a button --></div>
   <div style="margin-top: 110px;"><ul>..<!--Contains a list -->...</ul></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i did position to fixed then i lost the Jquery button styling

Comment: Are you setting `position: fixed` to this `<div data-role="button" data-theme="b">Something</div>`? If so, I would not do that. I would wrap it in another `div` and then set that `div` to `position: fixed`.

Comment: Still the same thing after wrapping in other div :(

Answer (score 0):

probably `data-position="fixed"` helps:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>Page1</h3>
      <div data-role="button" data-theme="b">Something</div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <div>
        <ul data-role="listview">
          ...
        </ul>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

see also [the docu here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

```
Fixed header markup example:
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

you also might want to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701287/jquery-mobile-why-fixed-header-footer-are-not-really-css-fixed)